# Совпадение сигнатур функции при импорте/экспорте из DLL

Tags: c++, c, dll, export

Насколько мне известно, при использовании `extern "C"`, в `DLL` не попадает сигнатура экспортируемой функции. То есть, для экспортируемой функции в `DLL` попадает ее имя и адрес входа.

Для того, чтобы использовать экспортированную функцию, мы получаем адрес входа, используя связанное с адресом входа имя.

Затем, чтобы использовать функцию извне, мы приводим полученный адрес к нужной сигнатуре. И затем - вызываем.

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем: насколько важно совпадение сигнатуры реальной функции, которая находится в `DLL`, и сигнатуры указателя, через который происходит вызов данной функции извне?

Раньше я думал, что главное - это совпадение количества и размера параметров. Например, извне в функцию передается аргумент типа `uint32_t`, а внутри `DLL` данный аргумент имеет тип `float`. Или `int32_t`.

Но недавно я узнал, что параметры и возвращаемое значение одинакового размера могут передаваться по-разному.

Значит ли это, что сигнатуры должны совпадать на 100%?

Или же, они могут не совпадать, если учитывать правила вызова и передачи аргументов/возвращаемых значений?

Comment: Не только сигнатура, но и соглашение о вызове...

Comment: Вызов функции через указатель на функцию с другой сигнатурой даже без dll является неопределенным поведением.